# Disable a group of checkboxes based on "Data attributes" and disabled-attribure

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following set of checkboxes:

```
<input class="lvl" type="checkbox" data-groupid="1" data-multichoice="1" checked />
<input class="lvl" type="checkbox" data-groupid="1" data-multichoice="1" />
<input class="lvl" type="checkbox" data-groupid="1" data-multichoice="1" />
<br />
<input class="lvl" type="checkbox" data-groupid="2" data-multichoice="0" />
<input class="lvl" type="checkbox" data-groupid="2" data-multichoice="0" />
<input class="lvl" type="checkbox" data-groupid="2" data-multichoice="0" checked />
<input class="lvl" type="checkbox" data-groupid="2" data-multichoice="0" />
<br />
<input class="lvl" type="checkbox" data-groupid="3" data-multichoice="1" />
<input class="lvl" type="checkbox" data-groupid="3" data-multichoice="1" checked />
<input class="lvl" type="checkbox" data-groupid="3" data-multichoice="1" />
<input class="lvl" type="checkbox" data-groupid="3" data-multichoice="1" />
<br />
<input class="lvl" type="checkbox" data-groupid="4" data-multichoice="0" />
<input class="lvl" type="checkbox" data-groupid="4" data-multichoice="0" />
<input class="lvl" type="checkbox" data-groupid="4" data-multichoice="0" />
<input class="lvl" type="checkbox" data-groupid="4" data-multichoice="0" />
```

I need to disable all checkboxes that have a `class="lvl"` and `data-multichoice="0"` **IF** there is a checkbox that is already checked in this group.
Therefore converting the scenario above to:

```
<input class="lvl" type="checkbox" data-groupid="1" data-multichoice="1" checked />
<input class="lvl" type="checkbox" data-groupid="1" data-multichoice="1" />
<input class="lvl" type="checkbox" data-groupid="1" data-multichoice="1" />
<br />
<input class="lvl" type="checkbox" data-groupid="2" data-multichoice="0" disabled />
<input class="lvl" type="checkbox" data-groupid="2" data-multichoice="0" disabled />
<input class="lvl" type="checkbox" data-groupid="2" data-multichoice="0" checked />
<input class="lvl" type="checkbox" data-groupid="2" data-multichoice="0" disabled />
<br />

<input class="lvl" type="checkbox" data-groupid="3" data-multichoice="1" />
<input class="lvl" type="checkbox" data-groupid="3" data-multichoice="1" checked />
<input class="lvl" type="checkbox" data-groupid="3" data-multichoice="1" />
<input class="lvl" type="checkbox" data-groupid="3" data-multichoice="1" />
<br />
<input class="lvl" type="checkbox" data-groupid="4" data-multichoice="0" />
<input class="lvl" type="checkbox" data-groupid="4" data-multichoice="0" />
<input class="lvl" type="checkbox" data-groupid="4" data-multichoice="0" />
<input class="lvl" type="checkbox" data-groupid="4" data-multichoice="0" />
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Since your last question asked few minutes ago, what happened??? Never you tried yourself something on your side before asking? If this is unrelated to your previous question, just let me know. And anyway, for user experience, use radio for unique choice and checkbox if multiple available, don't try unrelevant fix

Comment: why you're not even trying anything. This answer is sufficient for your question. [Your Question 10 minute before](http://bit.ly/1M2nMRo)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Enable or Disable checkbox based on Data attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33449735/enable-or-disable-checkbox-based-on-data-attribute)

Comment: I tried previous answer and it worked fine. But I encountered another scenario which is very different from what I asked earlier. I also decided to use radios instead, this will save the excessive JS. so thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```js
$('.lvl[data-multichoice="0"]').not(':checked').prop('disabled', true);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input class="lvl" type="checkbox" data-groupid="1" data-multichoice="1" checked />
<input class="lvl" type="checkbox" data-groupid="1" data-multichoice="1" />
<input class="lvl" type="checkbox" data-groupid="1" data-multichoice="1" />
<br />
<input class="lvl" type="checkbox" data-groupid="2" data-multichoice="0" />
<input class="lvl" type="checkbox" data-groupid="2" data-multichoice="0" />
<input class="lvl" type="checkbox" data-groupid="2" data-multichoice="0" checked />
<input class="lvl" type="checkbox" data-groupid="2" data-multichoice="0" />
<br />
<input class="lvl" type="checkbox" data-groupid="3" data-multichoice="1" />
<input class="lvl" type="checkbox" data-groupid="3" data-multichoice="1" checked />
<input class="lvl" type="checkbox" data-groupid="3" data-multichoice="1" />
<input class="lvl" type="checkbox" data-groupid="3" data-multichoice="1" />
```

Answer (score 1):

The above answer is correct this is just another way to re-enable all inputs of this group when all are unchecked.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $inputs = $(".lvl");
    function checkInput(){
        if( $('.lvl[data-groupid="2"]:checked').length > 0) {
            $('.lvl[data-groupid="2"]').not(':checked').prop('disabled', true);
        } else {
            $('.lvl[data-groupid="2"]').not(':checked').prop('disabled', false);
        }
    }

    // watch input change event
    $inputs.change(function() {
        checkInput();
    });

    // check inputs on DOM ready
    checkInput();
});
```

**EDIT**

As suggested you may want to use Radios if you want a single choice per group. 
This will make your Radios act like Checkboxes and toggle the state of the ones with the attribute

> `data-multichoice='0'` IF there is a checkbox that is already checked
>   in this group

```
    var $inputs = $(".lvl");
    $inputs.click(function() {

        var previousValue = $(this).attr('previousValue');

        // Make radios act like checkbox for same group
        var inputGroup = $("input[name="+ $(this).attr('name') +"]:radio");

        // Toggle Disable attr for radios of same group + data-multichoice="0"
        var targerGroup = $("input[name="+ $(this).attr('name') +"][data-multichoice='0']:radio");

        if (previousValue == 'checked')
        {

            $(this).removeAttr('checked');
            $(this).attr('previousValue', false);
            targerGroup.not(':checked').prop('disabled', false);

        }
        else
        {
            inputGroup.attr('previousValue', false);
            $(this).attr('previousValue', 'checked');
            targerGroup.not(':checked').prop('disabled', true);
        }

    });

 <input class="lvl" type="radio" name="group1"  data-groupid="1" data-multichoice="1" checked />
 <input class="lvl" type="radio" name="group1"  data-groupid="1" data-multichoice="1" />
 <input class="lvl" type="radio" name="group1"  data-groupid="1" data-multichoice="1" />
 <input class="lvl" type="radio" name="group2"  data-groupid="2" data-multichoice="0" disabled />
 <input class="lvl" type="radio" name="group2"  data-groupid="2" data-multichoice="0" disabled />
 <input class="lvl" type="radio" name="group2"  data-groupid="2" data-multichoice="0" checked />
 <input class="lvl" type="radio" name="group2"  data-groupid="2" data-multichoice="0" disabled />
 <input class="lvl" type="radio" name="group3"  data-groupid="3" data-multichoice="1" />
 <input class="lvl" type="radio" name="group3"  data-groupid="3" data-multichoice="1" checked />
 <input class="lvl" type="radio" name="group3"  data-groupid="3" data-multichoice="1" />
 <input class="lvl" type="radio" name="group3"  data-groupid="3" data-multichoice="1" />
 <input class="lvl" type="radio" name="group4"  data-groupid="4" data-multichoice="0" />
 <input class="lvl" type="radio" name="group4"  data-groupid="4" data-multichoice="0" />
 <input class="lvl" type="radio" name="group4"  data-groupid="4" data-multichoice="0" />
 <input class="lvl" type="radio" name="group4"  data-groupid="4" data-multichoice="0" />
```

Comment: this is an interesting approach, but has group ids hardcoded, I have an example on top, my scenario is more complex

Comment: @Andrew Check updated answer using radios. Does this answer your question ?